# Middleman single news post add active class to navigation

Tags: navigation, blogs, middleman, article

I am working with Middleman and I have been able to add a active class to the menu navigation depending if your on the page or not. So this works fine but not I have a News link in the navigation which takes you to a news overview page (this turns active) but I have a read more that takes you to a single news post. When it does this the News link is not active anymore because it thinks its not on this page anymore.

My folder structure is

```
aktuelles
  - index.html.erb (overview of all news articles)
  - kuendigungsschutz-fuer-geschaeftsfuehrer (single news article)
    - index.html.erb
```

So, I have provided some images. First shows the overview page and the aktuelles is highlight because we are on that page. But when you click the news article to read more you can see on the next image, aktuelles is not highlighted anymore and I would like it do be not sure how to do this. A helper in the config.rb but not sure what.

this is what I have for the navigation in the header

```
<li>
    <a class="<%= is_page_selected("/aktuelles/") %>" 
       href="/aktuelles">Aktuelles</a>
</li>
```

this is what I have for the a href when you click on the news article to read the whole thing.

I'm guessing something in this a href needs to change to make the aktuelles stay active when you click on this link?

```
<a class="teaser container" href="kuendigungsschutz-bei-kleinbetrieben-im-falle-einer-regelmasigen-beschaeftigung-von-leiharbeitnehmern">
    <sup>10.11.2015</sup>
    <h5 class="teaser__title mart-1">Kündigungsschutz bei Kleinbetrieben im 
        Falle einer regelmäßigen Beschäftigung von Leiharbeitnehmern
    </h5>
    <p>Arbeitnehmer haben nur dann Kündigungsschutz, wenn deren 
       Arbeitsverhältnis länger als 6 Monate besteht und der Arbeitgeber in der 
       Regel mehr als 10 vollzeitbeschäftigte Arbeitnehmer beschäftigt.
    </p>
    <p class="teaser__link">weiterlesen</p>
</a>
```

[news article overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFyiO.png)

[single news article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di5yD.png)

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot, it's the most concise way to achieve this with Middleman that I've found:

in config.rb:

```
helpers do
  def active_navigation(page)
    current_page.url.include?(page) ? "active" : ''
  end
end
```

and in your template, just define the path you'd like to check for:

```
<ul>
  <li class="<%= active_navigation("/aktuelles") %>">
   <%= link_to_page 'Aktuelles', '/aktuelles' %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now, on any page where URL path contains "/aktuelles", the li will have an "active" class applied.

So, /aktuelles, /aktuelles/abc, /aktuelles/123, etc., will all cause an active class to be applied.